# How can I do a thesis in life science, or can I?

Tags: research-process, thesis

I am a computer science drop out. But, currently, studying an MA in ESL. I took only one programming language course as an optional subject from the Faculty of life sciences and received an excellent (4 with bonus points) grade in theory, lab, and project.

Now, my professor, today sent me the following email:

> Hi,
>
> You are very welcome. It was my pleasure to work with you. Actually,
> your effort was much higher than the others.
>
> If you would look for an interesting programming project, we have
> plenty of options. We could try to find some funding for that. Also,
> If you consider an MSc thesis on life sciences, you might consider my
> group.
>
> Best regards,
> Mr. Professor
>
> Mr. Student `<`mr.student@university.edu`>` wrote:
>
> > Dear Sir,
> >
> > With due respect,
> >
> > Thank you very much for the grade (4+ = Excellent). I am grateful for
> > your kindness.
> >
> > Kind regards.
> > Mr. Student.

Now, I never studied life sciences in my life.

What options do I have in case I want to undertake a thesis under my professor? Or, is it really possible for me to take up a thesis under the faculty of life sciences?

Comment: It's likely that the prof can tell you if you could write this thesis if you tell him your background (in case he doesn't know yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, currently, studying an MA in ESL.

English as a second language? If your future plans are in this direction, it seems like doing research in the life sciences would not be relevant to your career.

From your question, I assume you are open to switching into a computer or life science stream. This question of "what do you want to be when you grow up?" is closely tied to your current dilemma. If you know what career you want, it is easy to decide whether this research experience would be a good use of time. If you don't know what career you want, pursuing this research experience might help you decide.

> What options do I have in case I want to undertake a thesis under my professor?

Talk to the professor. Before rearranging your life, you should get a better sense of he has in mind; further, you should make him aware of where you're coming from. Be transparent, but resist the temptation to use the professor as your therapist or career coach; rather, you should approach them even now as a prospective advisor or boss.

> Or, is it really possible for me to take up a thesis under the faculty of life sciences?

This will depend on your university's organization. I suspect you would have to apply for admission, which would likely require taking some of the undergraduate classes you are currently lacking. Again, your professor can advise you. This is potentially a lot of work, but it is the right thing to do *if* you want to get a job that requires an MSc in life sciences. Which brings us back to your career goals.

Comment: *what do you want to be when you grow up?* --- I want to be a professor in a tertiary level educational institute.