# Are US universities generally reluctant to admit PhD students who already hold a PhD?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, second-degree, stem

I am planning to do a Ph.D. in Math Education from one of the prominent universities in western Europe, and then do a Ph.D. in EEE/CSE.

The reason being, I have a STEM background but due to clinical depression and weak math background, I decided to drop out of the MSc in CS program. My age is running out and I feel that getting a Ph.D. in Education is a safer option, as Education is based on social science, and it is relatively less risky than getting involved in Ph.D. in CSE as science research regularly fails, and there is also a risk that some other guy may be already working on what I am getting started with. However, I am feeling a deep obsession with studying CSE and getting a Ph.D. in CSE.

My plan is to start a Ph.D. in math Education and repair my math and CS background simultaneously.

Are US universities reluctant in admitting Ph.D. students who already hold a Ph.D.?

If Yes, why and how to bypass that?

Comment: See also: [Is a second PhD ever necessary?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29764/is-a-second-phd-ever-necessary)

Comment: Also, I would reiterate my comments [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/155951/79875) -- namely, that you should figure out what job you want, then obtain the degrees that will qualify you for that job. One academic career is hard enough; trying to pursue two simultaneously will make things more risky, not less.